# Active State on slideshow arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class to when slider is active arrows should be active. E.g. if there are 5 images, and the user moves to the second one, the left arrow should remove the **disabled** class.

So both arrows will now be active to move left or right. If the user reaches 5th image, the arrow on the right is **disabled**.

This doesnt seem to want to work - can anyone provide a recommendation on a way i should take this forward.

```js
$('#product-gallery-super').children().click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var prodImg = $(this).attr('data-image');
    var imgSrc = $(this).children().attr('src')

    if (imgSrc != '/images/imagecomingsoon_en.jpg') {

        $(this).addClass("active-thumbnail").siblings().removeClass("active-thumbnail");

        $('.main-image').attr('src', prodImg);

    }

});

$("#prev").click(function () {

    if ($("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").prev().length != 0) {
        $("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").prev().addClass('active-thumbnail').next().removeClass('active-thumbnail');

        $('.main-image').attr('src', $('#product-gallery-super').find('.active-thumbnail').data('image'));

    }
    return false;
});

$("#next").click(function () {

    if ($("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").next().length != 0) {
        $("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").next().addClass('active-thumbnail').prev().removeClass('active-thumbnail');

        $('.main-image').attr('src', $('#product-gallery-super').find('.active-thumbnail').data('image'));

    }
    return false;
});
```

```css
.active-thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#prev{
    opacity:1;
}
#prev.disabled{
    opacity:0.5;
}

#next{
    opacity:1;
}
#next.disabled{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="main-image image-resize" src="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=1" data-zoom-image="http://placehold.it/1000x2000?text=1" onerror="comingSoonMain(this)">
<button name="prev" id="prev" class="disabled">Prev</button>
<button name="next" id="next">Next</button>
<div id="product-gallery-super"> <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery active-thumbnail" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=1">
  </a>
 <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=2">
  </a>
 <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=3">
  </a>
 <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=4">
  </a>
 <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=5">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=5">
  </a>
 <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=6">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: I think its better to see your code in action .. try to make JSFiddle .. and while you do that I didn't find removeClass('disabled') in your code

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef No need to make a jsfiddle - just scroll down on stack overflow and run the code snippet. Removing the class is fine but determining the 1st and last through children().length is causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry for that ..  you just need to use .index() +1  .. so if the active image with .index() + 1 > 1   so remove disabled class from prev button  just add +1 to index()  cause .index() start from 0

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed-Yousef Are you able to provide an simple example of usage?

Comment: does this work for you @SophieRhodes http://jsfiddle.net/Lygoea3y/?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/nukLy89u/2/ and check css as well

Comment: @ Sushil - there seems to be an issue with the line 36 as i am receiving a null on my implementation

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Works perfectly!!! thank you :)!

Comment: did you declare the global variable `currentImage` in the ready event? `var currentImage = null;`